# IEEE 754 addition wrong result floating point numbers

Tags: floating-point

I want to add two IEEE 754 numbers.
I followed the steps to add two 754 numbers. However the result it not correct.
Number 1:
S:0
E:01111111
M:11111111111111111111111

Number 2:
S:0
E:01111111
M:00000000000000000000000

Here is my calculation:

[image]

The site http://weitz.de/ieee/ gives this result:
S: 0
E: 10000000
M: 10000000000000000000000

in my calculation the mantissa is 01111...
Why?

Comment: If you have more than 10 bits, it's very helpful to add a space between groups of four bits.

Comment: In their calculation I see the same mantissa as yours.

Comment: What about *number of bits* & *rounding*?

Comment: Just rounding. Tere is one extra 1 on the right of the mantissa, with rounding 01111... becomes 10000.....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about one person making a mistake or misunderstanding something, and any answer would be completely useless for anyone else. Including OP who probably hasnt been stuck in this problem for three years.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the implicit leading 1 in the mantissa. The mantissa is not 23 bits, it's 24 bits with a 1 as the leading bit.

Comment: i did not forgot it. 1,111... and 1,000

Comment: Where do these 1,111... and 1,000 come from ??

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}1&.01111111 \\+1&.11111111111111111111111\\=11&.01111110111111111111111\end{align}$$

You obtain the same result with the calculator.